# Magento 2 : Static Timeout for Frontend Customers

Tags: magento2.3, customer-session, timeout

For my Magento 2 store, I want all logged in customers to log out after a fixed time of say 1 day, even if they are active on the store. How can I develop a custom module to achieve this?

Comment: This link might help you with customer session https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/customer-online-options.html

Comment: Thanks @Asssd ,As mentioned in the documentation, at this moment there is no setting in Admin that controls the length of server session for frontend customers. Is there a way, it can be achieved by developing a custom module or plugin

Comment: As per my knowledge and current docs this satisfies the requirment as I have used the same issue for time out where I have to increase the time out try once

Comment: Thanks, So, even though customer is active clicking on webstore, he will still be logged out after that time, Is it?

Comment: yes it wii be logout

Comment: Its not happening in my case, Im in Magento 2.3 and If i keep working with my mouse and keyboard. it doesnt gets logged out after I set cookie lifetime setting